# Size of product collection using getSize() method and using foreach loop is different-different Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, magento-community, magento2.4.2

I am using Magento version 2.4.2
We have total 278 configurable products showing in admin panel.
I want to get all configurable product collection in root using below code.
When I try to get total number of configurable product collection using getSize() method it is showing correct total 278 products but when I use foreach loop to get all 278 products then loop just running only 136 time.
Why this happening, please help me to resolve this issue.

Code(for Test):-

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require '../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

try{
    $count=0;
    $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
    $collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $configurablecollection = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'));
    echo $configurablecollection->getSize();
    echo "<br>";
    foreach ($configurablecollection as $configurableproduct) {
        $count++;
    }
    echo $count;
    exit();
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $msg = 'Error : '.$e->getMessage();die();
}
```

Output expected:-
278
278

**Output getting:-
278
136**

Comment: Did you checked in the DB, how many configurable products are there?

Comment: In which table in database I can count the total no of configurable products?

Comment: You can check it in *catalog_product_entity* table.

Comment: @RahulBarot Yes, this table is showing 278 records for configurable products.

Comment: try reload the collection after the <br>, let me know if the count now works

Comment: @AlanZavagli Reloaded using "$configurablecollection->load()" but still count not working.